# Implementing "select distinct ... from ..." over a list of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is my problem: I have a list of Python dictionaries of identical form, that are meant to represent the rows of a table in a database, something like this:

```
[ {'ID': 1,
   'NAME': 'Joe',
   'CLASS': '8th',
   ... },
  {'ID': 1,
   'NAME': 'Joe',
   'CLASS': '11th',
   ... },
  ...]
```

I have already written a function to get the unique values for a particular field in this list of dictionaries, which was trivial. That function implements something like:

`select distinct NAME from ...`

However, I want to be able to get the list of multiple unique fields, similar to:

`select distinct NAME, CLASS from ...`

Which I am finding to be non-trivial. Is there an algorithm or Python included function to help me with this quandry?

Before you suggest loading the CSV files into a SQLite table or something similar, that is not an option for the environment I'm in, and trust me, that was my first thought.

Comment: Do you want all unique pairs, or all unique Names, and then unique Classes, separately?

Comment: if you can do it with one field what the problem is of doing it with two or more?.

Comment: @Claudiu I want the unique pairs. If I wanted them separately, I could just call the function twice. To do it with one or two field names is not an issue, it's generalizing to `N` number of fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want it as a generator:

```
def select_distinct(dictionaries, keys):
  seen = set()
  for d in dictionaries:
    v = tuple(d[k] for k in keys)
    if v in seen: continue
    yield v
    seen.add(v)
```

if you want the result in some other form (e.g., a list instead of a generator) it's not hard to alter this (e.g., `.append` to the initially-empty result list instead of `yield`ing, and return the result list at the end).

To be called, of course, as

```
for values_tuple in select_distinct(thedicts, ('NAME', 'CLASS')):
    ...
```

or the like.

Answer (score 0):

distinct_list =  list(set([(d['NAME'], d['CLASS']) for d in row_list]))

where row_list is the list of dicts you have

Answer (score 0):

One can implement the task using hashing. Just hash the content of rows that appear in the distinct query and ignore the ones with same hash.